# Why Images Not Loading - CodeSandbox

Tags: image, codesandbox

Please take a look at my [CodeSandbox](https://b9i0f.csb.app/) to find reason(s) why images not loading, as well as what should be mindful way to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

well in my case it was antivirus software which was blocking codesandbox's link from loading images, stop browser protection in your antivirus or put this website in exception list if that feature is available